# Missing number, treated as zero with nested tabu

Tags: color, tabu

I have this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} {|ll|}
  a & \begin{tabu}{l}
    1 \\
    red 2 \\
  \end{tabu} \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Using pdflatex from texlive 20120628 on cygwin gives me this error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
               \tabu@1.H0
l.13 \end{longtabu}
```

If I leave out `\usepackage{colortbl}` the error is gone. Unfortunately my actual document is a lot larger and I need this package.

Using pdflatex from MiKTex 2.9 gives me no error.

Where does this error come from and how can I fix it? I need to be able to compile this document using texlive as well.

Comment: `tabu` has its own methods for coloring cells; it should check for compatibility with the standard LaTeX tools, though, but apparently it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm appears `tabu` doesn't want to nest. This works round it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\grumble
\savebox\grumble{%
\begin{tabu}{l}
    1 \\
    red 2 \\
  \end{tabu}%
}

\begin{longtabu} {|ll|}
  a & \usebox{\grumble} \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since my code is partially generated it is difficult to use your suggested method. Looking further into this I discovered that texlive uses version v1.0a of the colortbl package while MiKTex uses version v0.1j. This explains the different behavior. Copying the older colortbl.sty file next to my .tex file solves the compilation error.

Comment: ah that's unfortunate as it means it is harder to blame the author of tabu. Clearly one wouldn't want to blame the author of colortbl. I'll see if I can see what the difference is.

Comment: @David Carlisle: On a fully updated MikTex 2.9 distribution I am experiencing the same problem. I wonder whether there is some solution you would suggest.

Comment: @Marcos: For me this is also true. I have a TeX document here, which is also using `tabu` in conjunction with `colortbl` and nested `tabu` environments. When I compile this document using a fully-updated MiKTeX system with `colortbl` v1.0a I'm running into the same errors, but using version v0.1j of `colortbl`, I have no problems.