# LaTeX nested tabu in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, tabu

I have a nested tabu environment in the moderncv class

```
\documentclass{moderncv} 
\usepackage{tabu} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Smith} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{tabu}{|X|X|} 
   hello & hey\\ 
   nested & \begin{tabu}{X} 
      yes\\no\\ 
   \end{tabu} 
\end{tabu} 

\end{document}
```

which gets me the error

```
|17 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \tabu@1.H0  \end{tabu}                       
|17 error| Missing = inserted for \ifdim. \tabu@1.H0  \end{tabu}
|17 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \tabu@1.H0  \end{tabu}
```

It works fine if I change the class to article for example. Does anyone now the conflict with moderncv here?

Comment: I want to add that this worked a couple of months ago, so it might be a change in modercv. (Upgrade OpenSuSe 42.3->15.0)

Answer (score 1):

The conflict is probably not with `moderncv`, but with the `colortbl` package, which gets loaded by `moderncv` via `\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}`.

This conflict occured after an update of the `colortbl` package. [Compare with this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81905/missing-number-treated-as-zero-with-nested-tabu) There is also a workaround for nesting with `tabu`.